# Округление дробных чисел в python

Tags: python

Всем привет! Мне нужно напечатать в консоль дробное число например 100.000000
меня x = 100.000001. Как его правильно округлить?

Comment: 100.000000 = 100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы вывести число 100.000000 на нужно округлить число 100.000001 не более чем до пятого знака после запятой. Тогда у нас число превратится в 100. Чтобы вывести его с шестью нулями, воспользуемся методом форматирования вещественных чисел.

```
print("{0:.6f}".format(round(100.000001, 5)))
```

Вывод:

```
100.000000
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: round не нужно тут в примере

Comment: @eri, почему это не нужно? https://ideone.com/AVQ1L1

Comment: @dmytros98 чтобы вывести 6 цифр после запятой, но округлить до пяти знаков в фиксированном формате: `"%.5f0" % 100.000001`

Comment: @КириллМалышев это больше вопрос к @dmytros98 - зачем ему нолик в конце я не знаю. `.6f` уже содержит в себе алгоритм округления и округлять  таким каскадом не нужно в 99.99% случаев