# Как округлять значение в цикле python

Tags: python

```
import time 
import math

x = int(input ("задай число "))

while x > 5 :
    print(f"{x}на 2 ={x/2}")
    x /= 2
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

нужно чтобы выводилось округленное значение

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Округление дробных чисел в python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/657192/%d0%9e%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d0%b2-python)

Comment: Какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: Как именно должно округлять? Если до целого, то просто целочисленное округление используйте через `//`

Answer (score 2):

С помощью функции `round()`.
Она принимает два значения `round(float_number, number_of_decimals)` где `float_number` представляет собой число, которое нужно округлить, а `number_of_decimals` определяет, до какой цифры будет округлено число. Функция возвращает float. Если `number_of_decimals` не указано, то по умолчанию там стоит ноль. В таком случае округление происходит до ближайшего целого и возвращается тоже целое число.

Пример:

```
a = 6.55572

print(round(a, 2))
print(round(a))
print(round(a, 4))
```

Вывод:

```
6.56
7
6.5557

[Program finished]
```

Из этого следует, что ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```
import time 
import math

x = int(input ("задай число "))

while x > 5 :
    print(f"{x} на 2 = {round(x/2, 2)}")
    x /= 2
    time.sleep(0.1)
```